# Check numpy array shape is () and if so reshape to (1,)

Tags: reshape, numpy-ndarray

I have a function that may return a single value as numpy array:

```
print(yhat, yhat.shape)
Output: 0.9337081 ()
```

How to check that numpy array shape is () and if so reshape it to (1,)? So as a result to get:

```
yhat = np.array([0.9337081])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already verifying that the shape of yhat is equal to `()` by printing `yhat.shape`. If you want to reshape a numpy array use [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

```
>>> yhat = np.array(0.9337081)
>>> yhat.shape
()
>>> yhat.shape == ()
True
>>> yhat = yhat.reshape(-1,)
>>> yhat.shape
(1,)
>>> yhat
array([0.9337081])
```